# How do I count cycles of ONLY length 1 and length 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As of right now, it seems like I am counting the total number of cycles in a graph instead of just the length 1 and length 2 cycles. Here is my code below. I feel like I am doing something wrong, but I cannot figure out what that is.

A sample input would be:

12 13 23 31 34 41

which is the number of edges.

The output would be 1 since there are 0 length one cycles and 1 length 2 cycle.

```
temp_list = list(edges)
    nodes = int((max(temp_list)))
    def multi(M1, M2, nodes):

        new = []
        for i in range (nodes):
            arrow = []
        for j in range (nodes):
            sum = 0
        for k in range (nodes):
            sum += M1[i][k] * M2[k][j]
            arrow.append(sum)
            new.append(arrow)
        return new
    def cYcLeS(M, nodes):
        cycles = 0
        for i in range(nodes):
            cycles += M[i][i]
        return cycles
  
    M = []
    for i in range (nodes):
        row = []
    for j in range (nodes):
        row.append(0)
        M.append(row)
    for e in edges.split():
        M[int(e[0])-1][int(e[1])-1] = 1
    second = multi(M, M, nodes)
    return cYcLeS(M, nodes)//1
    return cYcLeS(second, nodes)//2
```

Comment: Unless you're writing this yourself for practice or the hell of it, I'd suggest just using the [Networkx](https://networkx.org/) library.

Comment: please make sure code is formatted as in your code, and tabs are correctly aligned.